# Xcode 6 - Using Size Classes with iPhone 4/5

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios8, xcode6

So I have seen a few posts coming out about this, but I am having a ridiculous time withe the Class Sizes in the new storyboard. Following the guides from apple and online, I can't get the sizing to work with the 3.5 or 4 inch screens without compressing everything on the larger screens.

Here is my Any/Any

[image]

And here is what I get:

[image]

I have tried a ton of different constraints and I can't get it to work. Mainly, I want to be able to keep the proportional spacing with the different screen sizes.

What constraints am I missing? (they are all blue now)

Is there a good guide out there for this yet?

EDIT: How do you get the layout to work for the 3.5 and 4 inch screens without compressing everything on the larger screens also? What constraints or Size Class settings do you need?

Comment: Can you describe more specifically what you want to happen?

Comment: tried to make it more clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the layout to work"? Be specific - "the X edge of ___ view is at Y but I want it to be at Z".

Comment: The top edge is set to be X points from the top view in the any/any layout, and yet they are still under the Nav bar on the 4" and 3.5". How do you make the any/any or the compact/any work with the new Autolayout and size classes without compressing all the views? I don't know how else to explain this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top view should have these constraints:

- Top Space to Top Layout Guide = 20 (or whatever)
- Two horizontal constraints; for example:

  - Align Center X to Superview
  - Width = 300

When viewing the Any/Any view, click on the top text field, and select **All** under **Constraints**.  Make sure there are no other constraints that might be different when the view is constrained.

Here's a screenshot of what your constraint setup should look like:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of it working great on a 3.5" iPhone:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Man I don't know why that was so hard for me to figure out. Worked a treat.